# Is there a limit to review-audits enabled?

Tags: feature-request, review-audits

I've just got out of the review queues in SO, and I had *twenty* review audits in a row (on three queues).

I'm not fault-proof, but it seems a bit excessive to be tested so many times in a row.

Is there a limit to the audit count? If there's not, how can I suggest its implementation?